# Mouse in 2-port USB sharing device not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, 16.04, mouse

I use an Aten 2-Port USB sharing device to share mouse and keyboard between two computers. Under Ubuntu 14.04 this worked fine but after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 my Steelseries Kinzu V2 mouse is not working anymore.

The keyboard including trackpad still works and the mouse works when plugged in a separate USB port of either computer, i.e. not using the sharing device. Using *xinput*

```
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Kinzu V2 Gaming Mouse         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And *lsusb*

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1038:1366 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 17ef:6047 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does anybody know a fix?